# C++ Using vectors within vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, vector, stdvector

I have a function that needs to return two vectors so I have been using a vector within a vector to return them right now I have unsuccessfully tried doing:

The error I got is

> Unhandled exception at at 0x769E4598 in OOP project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00CAF490.

```
vector<vector<string>> mainVector;
vector<string> vector1;
vector<string> vector2:

mainVector.reserve(2);
mainVector.push_back(vector1);
mainVector.push_back(vector2);

return mainVector;
```

so my question is how do you do I add a vector to another vector?
this is my entire code:

```
vector < vector < string >> connectedJourney(string airpCode1, string airpCode2, vector < string > flights) {
  vector < vector < string >> rawMatches;
  vector < string > deptMatchesTemp;
  vector < string > destMatchesTemp;
  vector < string > deptMatches;
  for (unsigned int f1 = 0; f1 < flights.size(); f1++) { //store all the fligths that match the departure airport into deptMatches

    if (airpCode1 == flights[f1].substr(0, 3)) {

      deptMatches.push_back(flights[f1]);
    }
  }

  vector < string > destMatches;

  for (unsigned int f2 = 0; f2 < flights.size(); f2++) { //store all the fligths that match the departure airport into deptMatches

    string code = flights[f2];

    if (code.length() > 7 && airpCode2 == flights[f2].substr(4, 3)) {

      destMatches.push_back(flights[f2]);
    }
  }

  if (deptMatches.size() == 0 || destMatches.size() == 0) { // check if there won't be any matches
    cout << "no entries";
    throw noEntryFound();

  } else {
    vector < string > cj_Matches; //connected journey matches
    for (unsigned int g1 = 0; g1 < deptMatches.size() - 1; g1++) {
      cout << deptMatches.at(0);
      for (unsigned int g2 = 0; g2 < destMatches.size() - 1; g2++) {
        cout << deptMatches.at(1);
        if (deptMatches[g1].substr(4, 3) == destMatches[g2].substr(0, 3)) { //if the arrival place of the first flight matches the departure place of the first flight then the details of both flights are saved into a vector within another
          deptMatchesTemp.push_back(deptMatches[g1]);
          destMatchesTemp.push_back(deptMatches[g2]);
        }
      }
    }
    rawMatches.reserve(2);
    rawMatches.push_back(deptMatchesTemp);
    rawMatches.push_back(destMatchesTemp);
    return rawMatches;
  }

}

//I try to view the contents like this and I get an out or range error
vector < vector < string >> connectedMatches = connectedJourney(airpCode1, airpCode2, rawFlights);

cout << connectedMatches[1].at(0);
```

Comment: You're missing a `>`. Other than that, you're adding the vectors correctly.

Comment: Typo: you need `vector<vector<string>> mainVector;`

Comment: This is exactly how you do it. If it's not the typo in the original question, it's an error in the rest of the code which you're not showing to us. An alternative is using a `std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>>` or a `std::array<std::vector<std::string>, 2>` (only applicable if it's always exactly two vectors)

Comment: How is what you are doing "unsuccessful"?  Was there an error message when you compiled?  Did a large man show up and fine you for needless use of the free store?  Or for needlessly generating copies of data?  Did your code generate a run time message?  In addition, did you ACTUALLY COMPILE and run the ACTUAL CODE you are showing us to confirm the error in question is ACTUALLY caused by the code you are showing us?

Comment: I added my actual code, that was an example of what I was doing unsuccesfully

Comment: @Nimajik What's the error you get? (Note that I'm just guessing that you get an error, since you didn't say you get one.)

Comment: @zenith He actually does, though it's hidden in the wall of code. (Look at the last four lines of code)

Comment: I got: Unhandled exception at at 0x769E4598 in OOP project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00CAF490.

Comment: @stefan Oh right, that wasn't easy to find.

Comment: @zenith Very true, I edited the question to display it more prominently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run into an "out or range error" (actually, it's an exception which is a special kind of error), because the vectors may be empty:

```
cout << connectedMatches[1].at(0);
                         ^  ^
                         |  |
                         |  Access to first element, if available, 
                         |  otherwise exception will be thrown.
                         |
                         |
                         Unsafe access to the second element (only
                         recommended if access must be fast and you're
                         certain that you're allowed to access)
```

There are two ways to directly access the data of a vector: the subscript operator `operator[]` and the `at` method. The result will be the same if the provided index is valid. However behavior differs if the index is out of range: `operator[]` will not guarantee an error (but it may do anything from crashing to seemingly working fine, very dangerous!). `at` guarantees an exception that tells you that the index wasn't valid.

So you're experiencing the exception thing. There are two ways around this:

1. Don't access!

Avoid the access is simple, test if the vector is empty or not.

```
if ( connectedMatches[1].empty() )
{
    std::cerr << "No element to display!\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << connectedMatches[1].at(0);
}
```

2. Catch the exception:

This first tries to execute the code and will handle the error only it an error occurred.

```
try
{
    std::cout << connectedMatches[1].at(0);
}
catch ( const std::exception& e )
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `vector<string>` reference as parameter:

```
void connectedJourney(string airpCode1, string airpCode2, vector < string > flights, vector < string >& outputDeparture, vector < string >& outputDestination) {
  // Do your stuff using reference parameter instead of temp vector
  //...
  //...

}
```

In this case you don't need to return anything, you just have to create your 2 `vector<string>` before the function call and pass them to the function (2 last parameters in my example).

```
vector<string> myDeparture;
vector<string> myDestination;
connectedJourney(airpCode1, airpCode2, rawFlights, myDeparture, myDestination);

if (!myDeparture.empty()) cout << myDeparture.at(0);
else cout<<"Your departure vector is empty"

if (!myDestination.empty()) cout << myDestination.at(0);
else cout<<"Your destination vector is empty"
```

Comment: And how on earth would that help if the code that populates the vectors is buggy?

Comment: @juanchopanza Thx. I updated my answer to take into account the fact that the vector might be empty

Comment: The point is your change doesn't solve the problem, but makes the interface less robust. So overall, loss for no gain.